# Header won't stretch to 100% when viewport resized, but footer will?

Tags: css, header, width, viewport

I'm working on a small site, and I've searched for an answer to no avail.

Both my header and footer are set to width:100%, along with the wrapper divs around them, and the body.

My header is not stretching to 100%, and it's even worse when I have to scroll horizontally, but my footer is filling the width properly.  They're styled almost identically - I can't figure it out.

Here is the test site:

http://www.maxsitedesign.com/joncollins

Any help would be appreciated. At this point I've probably added extraneous styles in an attempt to fix it.

Comment: -1 for "At this point I've probably added extraneous styles in an attempt to fix it". It's unrealistic to expect people to answer questions on a changing piece of code.

Comment: +1 to compensate for odd -1 by Andrew.  All he did was try to find the issue.  That doesn't mean it's "a changing piece of code".  Furthermore, most questions on SO are for in progress projects which by nature of being "in progress" have changing code.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the following rule fixes it.

```
.inside {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

***style.css** line 60*

Basically what's happening is you are trying to apply a rule that should apply to the main content text only to the 100% width containers.  100% only applies to the actual width of the element and not the ultimate width.  Thus your containers were 100% + 20px (10px for each side).

#### EDIT:

Took another look at the site and it appears the problem is now with #spray and #bottom-wrapper.  You should remove the `width:1300px` from `#spray` and the `min-width:1300px` from `#bottom-wrapper`.  Those pixel sizes are conflicting with your % sizes.

Comment: Hi @Joseph, thank you so much for the help  - unfortunately I've removed that style and I still get a little gap on the upper right of the header - about twice the size of the scrollbar. I wouldn't be so flummoxed save for what I mentioned above about the footer working properly.  Continuing to troubleshoot...

Comment: @Max I took another look at the code and I may have found the issue.  Please see my edit.